# Error in Javascript when returning coordinates from Google Earth API

Tags: javascript, html, api, events, click

I am very new to Javascript, and have only very limited experience with HTML as well.  I am trying to incorporate the Google API 3 into a Delphi application, but I'm running into issues with the Javascript.

The basic functionality I require is to click on the Google Map, and return the coordinates to the Delphi application for use elsewhere.  I can open the google map, and even register the click event to place a marker and zoom the screen (thanks to some really good advice from this forum).  But when I try to retrieve the coordinates, my system returns an error message "Object doesn't support property or method 'getLatitude'.

I have also tried this with

```
function RetrieveCoords(event) {
  var lat = event.latlng.lat();
  var lng = event.latlng.lng(); 
  var alt = event.getaltitude();
placeMarker(event.latLng, map)  
}
```

I haven't yet implemented the part where I retrieve the values from Delphi, but there is a good example here(), and that will require the Javascript to function properly.  Can someone please help?

I'm using the following html code in a Delphi XE5 (VCL) application with a TWebbrowser.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"> </script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-26.0,24.019213); 
    var myOptions = { 
      zoom: 5, 
      center: latlng, 
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP 
    }; 
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), myOptions); 

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', RetrieveCoords)
    }   

function RetrieveCoords(event) {
  var lat = event.getLatitude();
  var lng = event.getLongitude(); 
  var alt = event.getaltitude();
placeMarker(event.latLng, map)  
}   


function placeMarker(position, map) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: position,
    map: map
  });
  map.panTo(position);
}

</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I've played around with this and eventually got it working.  There were several problems, and I think a combination of them caused my program not to work.

For starters, being a Delphi user I was not use to Javascript being case sensitive.  So the line 
`event.latlng.lat()` does not work, but
`event.latLng.lat()` does.

The GetLatitude syntax has apparently been discarded with Google API V3

Perhaps this little monologue I had helps someone else in the future...